# Installation Of Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

I have download cassandra via terminal but problem is where are the other folders like data, conf, lib, doc etc. 
i can see only some files as shown in figure i.e [Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8qpq9.png)
where is the other folders ?

Comment: Maybe this post can help you ? I think cassandra create data directory and files only if keyspace or data is created.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47709584/cassandra-installation

Answer (score 1):

By "download cassandra via terminal" and your screenshot, I'll assume that you installed Cassandra via `apt-get`.

From the [Apache Cassandra project Wiki](http://cassandra.apache.org/doc/latest/getting_started/installing.html#installation-from-debian-packages), section on Installation from Debian packages:

- The default location of configuration files is `/etc/cassandra`.
- The default location of log and data directories is `/var/log/cassandra/` and `/var/lib/cassandra`.

As for the `lib` directory, check how your `$CASSANDRA_HOME` is being set:

```
$ grep CASSANDRA_HOME /etc/init.d/cassandra
CASSANDRA_HOME=/usr/share/cassandra
$ ls -al /usr/share/cassandra/
total 8312
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root    4096 Dec 13 07:57 .
drwxr-xr-x 372 root root   12288 Nov 28 08:51 ..
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 5962385 Jun  1  2016 apache-cassandra-3.6.jar
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root      24 Jun  1  2016 apache-cassandra.jar -> apache-cassandra-3.6.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root 1902216 Jun  1  2016 apache-cassandra-thrift-3.6.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root     875 May 31  2016 cassandra.in.sh
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root   12288 Dec 13 07:57 lib
-rw-r-----   1 root root   82123 Oct 20  2015 metrics-core-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r-----   1 root root    9639 Oct 20  2015 metrics-graphite-2.2.0.jar
-rw-r--r--   1 root root  509144 Jun  1  2016 stress.jar
```

Note that Cassandra's `lib` directory is shown in the middle of the directory listing above.